My answer was deleted
Hi I just joined this site/forum today so I'm fairly new here and don't know how everything here works yet, also I'm currently using my phone to use this page which makes it a bit difficult to navigate on here
So back to my question. I answered this question and my answer was deleted What happened with Iwao Kuroiwa and Yukinori Shinohara after the battle against Yoshimura?
The thing is I stumbled upon this question simply by a Google search since I was looking up something. I saw the question which I already knew the answer to. The previous answer didn't include a specific detail. The detail I'm talking about is Shinohara woke up from his coma and isn't in a vegetative state anymore which wasn't mentioned in the previous answer
So since I just created my profile I wasn't able to directly reply to the previous answer so I decided to write a new answer with the missing information
It wasn't my intention to break any rules. I just wanted to clarify something and therefore I'm posting this here because I can't participate in the chat yet since my rank is still too low
I'm sorry if this post got a bit long but I think the additional info was needed to explain my point and clear up the misunderstanding
Also might there be a chance that the deletion of my answer could be undone?

Welcome, and thanks for opening a discussion about your answer in civil manner. I was the mod who deleted your answer. The reason was precisely what кяαzєя has explained, that it's so similar that I missed the fact about a single, little difference. Now that I realized my mistake, I've undeleted your answer. Sorry about that. Meanwhile, please follow кяαzєя's advice on how to improve your answer. Thanks for your understanding.

Thank you. I was confused for a second when I saw that my answer was deleted and was like, what did I do wrong ?

Just wanted to let you know that I just edited my answer and shared a link of the moment where the character wakes up from his coma

Welcome to our site. It may be disappointing to see your answer deleted, but such actions are taken in order to curate higher quality answers to questions, especially if there is an existing one that have almost identical information without any citations.
If you would like to contribute a better answer to an existing one, I would recommend citing sources (i.e., citing the chapter something happens, or providing a screen of the chapter) from the manga, rather than a wiki (they are considered tertiary source and not reliable since anyone can edit them), to reinforce the the points mentioned of your answer. This way when you compare the answers side by side, you'll have the clearer more authoritative that cites the source material to back things up.
You're free to either make a new answer citing sources or edit your existing deleted answer with citations.

Thank you for your explanation. I will edit my comment later once I have the Manga in my hand. Also how do you put spoilers in these hidden spoiler boxes?
